# org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: javascript, eclipse, model-view-controller, nullpointerexception, dispatcher

Doing MVC with Eclipse,

1. If start with `com.controller.main/mainServlet.java`, the list comes out well.
2. but if start in `WebContect/main.jsp`, through `Webcontent/goods/goodsList.jsp`, get this error.

In Servlet, either

RequestDispatcher dis = request.getRequestDispatcher("main.jsp");

or

RequestDispatcher dis = request.getRequestDispatcher("goods/goodsList.jsp");,

**anyway if start in main.jsp there is an error.**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.goods.goodsList_jsp._jspService(goodsList_jsp.java:139)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:713)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:519)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:865)
    at org.apache.jsp.main_jsp._jspService(main_jsp.java:137)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1626)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

`at org.apache.jsp.goods.goodsList_jsp._jspService(goodsList_jsp.java:139)`

this part. is here. i really wondering...

```
<%
    List<GoodsDTO> list = (List<GoodsDTO>)request.getAttribute("goodsList");
    for( int i = 1; i <=  list.size(); i++ ){
        GoodsDTO dto = list.get(i+1);
        String gCode = dto.getgCode();
        String gCategory = dto.getgCategory();
        String gName = dto.getgName();
        String gContent = dto.getgContent();
        int gPrice = dto.getgPrice();
        String gImage = dto.getgImage();
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the difference between the two ways you start the App, but from your `List<GoodsDTO>` logic this part:

```
for( int i = 1; i <=  list.size(); i++ ){
        GoodsDTO dto = list.get(i+1);
```

should throw IndexOutOfBoundException. As when you increment `i` to `list.size` and then do `list.get(i+1)`, it will be out of the list size. If you start with `i=1`, `list.get(i-1)` should help you avoid it.
Maybe this is somehow connected to NPE you are getting? but then it is strange that it works when you start with the first method you listed.